# Dynamic Accordion Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, html, accordion

I'm trying to create a dynamic accordion menu that pulls its selection from a database... Unfortunately all I'm getting is a list of the items, not in accordion format. Any ideas on what I need to fix?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3s9ug1ko/)

[Ends up looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cI2od.jpg)

You guys can't access the database so I'm just giving an image so you know what I'm getting. It seems to be the second function in the GenMenu is causing this issue. I just did another test menu generation function and the accordion came out perfectly... Any help would be appreciated

```
function GenTest()
{
    for (var i=0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        $('#Items').append('<h3>Test</h3><div><p>This is a Test</p></div>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
$("#Items").accordion( "refresh" );
```

to the end of your GetMenu function

And it's `h4` in your jsFidle example

```
 '<h4>' + _sItemArray.DATA.ITEMNO[i] + '</h4>'
```

Is it by intention?
I think it should by `h3`?

Comment: Oh yea, that was me just probably trying out random things, I'll switch back to h3

Comment: Also, added the refresh so it looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fets3jpz/) now and it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jquery accordion panel :https://jqueryui.com/accordion/ and use the innerHTML property instead of the append property, i have written an example for you in jsfiddle platform.

Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RockAnne/32qmmy9y/1/

```
    $(function() {
    for (var i=0; i < 5; i++)
    {
     document.getElementById("accordion").innerHTML +="<h3>Test</h3><div><p>This is a Test</p></div>";
    }

    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
       collapsible: true,
       heightStyle: "content"
    });
    });
```